# Как правильно отсортировать имена файлов?

Tags: android, сортировка

Пишу приложение, которое выбирает изображения, и выводит их

```
final List<Uri> files = getSelectedFilesFromResult(data);
```

Изображения названы так: 1.png, 11.png, 110.png, 2.png, 21.png, 3.png - в папке они находятся также
При сорте у меня получается 1.png, 11.png, 110.png, 2.png, 21.png, 3.png
Как отсортировать, чтобы получилось 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, 11.png, 21.png, 110.png

Comment: Покажите как вы сортируете в данный момент

Comment: Это называется Alphanumeric sort или Natural sort. Для Java гуглятся какие-то велосипеды

Comment: если нет имен с ведущими нулями, можно сделать сравнить по длине (длинные больше), а если равны - то посимвольно (`Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(s -> s)`).

Answer (score 0):

Переименуйте названия так:

```
String unpadded = "1"; // Имя файла 
String padded = "000".substring(unpadded.length()) + unpadded;
```

Или так:

```
String padded = String.format("%03d", Integer.parseInt(unpadded));
```

На выходе 001 .. 100, отсортируется правильно